# SQL server collation concept in join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why having consistent collation is important when you use joins?

I've used collation while joining two tables across two databases but why we need it?
If you've same collation on both tables on two different database do we need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collations define rules for string sorting and comparison - [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184391.aspx).

Personally, I use this query style -

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t1.KeyCD COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.KeyCD COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: You don't need to put COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT on both sides on JOIN. Only one on either side will work the same.